# Can't PUT from Android to DJANGO REST

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I have a DJANGO REST server on my personal network that is set up to get and receive JSON strings to update "statuses" for a project I'm working on. I can GET the information down into my Android application just fine but when I try to PUT information up to the server, I get the error:

> Bad Request: /api/users/1/
>   [28/Oct/2019 21:23:23] "PUT /api/users/1/ HTTP/1.1" 400 107

I think it's the app because I can successfully do a PUT request via Windows Powershell, but it doesn't work on the Android app. Here is the code using the OKHTTP class:

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
String content = String.format("{'status':%s}", selectedStatus);
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, content);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(IPAddress + "api/users/" + currentUserID + "/")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .put(body) //PUT
        .build();

client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I have tried using the standard HttpURLConnection class, which is what I did for the GET method, but I don't even get a response from the server when I do that. I've tried about a dozen ways to PUT something to the server, but nothing has worked. Any help achieving this goal would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking at this later, I found the issue. It turns out that in the Windows Powershell, you can use single quotes in the JSON string, but you NEED to use double quotes with the OKHTTP methods. Thus, I changed:

```
String content = String.format("{'status':%s}", selectedStatus);
```

to:

```
String content = String.format("{\"status\":%s}", selectedStatus);
```

and everything went through perfectly. Hope this helps someone.